# Can I use USB 3.0 port to power RPI4 + external SSD?

Tags: pi-4, power-supply, usb-power

On the Pi-4B, can I use one of the USB 3.0 ports for power, instead of the USB-C port?

I will be powering the Pi-4, an SSD drive ([Sabrent 512GB Rocket Nano](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XL6QYMV)), and a [Conbee II](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07PZ7ZHG5) — which btw currently works great using the official 5V/3A Pi power supply. I'm just working in a tight space and would prefer to use one of the 3.0 ports, to reduce the PI's profile if at all possible (rather than having a USB-C cable sticking out of the side).

Specifically, I'm thinking of using the [Anker Nano Pro](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B099F2H5KH), which has a rated output of 20W, 5V == 3A / 9V == 2.22A, using a USB-C to USB-A cable. I assume this would work as it matches the official power supply rating, but please correct me if I'm wrong. Happy to get a larger supply if needed. Cost really isn't an issue. The bigger question is regarding the USB 3.0 port.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

No.

The USB ports are connected via a current limiter.

You can power through pins 4/6.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I'm not sure I understand what that means. No power via USB 2/3 or mini usb?